# Apply multiple functions to GroupBy object in a specific order

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` with at column `date` which consists of date.

If I want to calculate the maximum difference between the dates within each group, is that doable (without having to re-group and without using `.apply`)? If I do

```py
df

id | date |
---+-------
1  | 2020-01-20
1  | 2020-01-25
2  | 2020-02-03
2  | 2020-02-04

max_diff_for_each_id = df.groupby("id").diff(1).max()
max_diff_for_each_id 

id
--
1  5
```

that of course give the maximum difference between all groups, where I want

```py
id 
--
1  5
2  1
```

I know I can just re-group `max_diff_for_each_id` but I think that

```py
max_diff_for_each_id = df.groupby("id").diff(1).groupby("id").max()
```

is not really "pretty" and say you have multiple functions to apply, there is a ton of overhead by having to re-group all the time

Comment: Can a group have more than two dates?

Comment: What is the reason no to use agg, if you used a vectorized function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is that doable (without having to re-group and without using .apply)

I think generally not, if only 2 values per groups or some another patterns of data there should be alternatives.

```
#if always 2 values per id in order
df1 = df.groupby("id")['date'].agg(['min','max'])
max_diff_for_each_id = df1['max'].sub(df1['min']).dt.days
```

Or:

```
#if always 2 values per id 
df2 = df.groupby("id")['date'].agg(['first','last'])

max_diff_for_each_id = df2['last'].sub(df2['first']).dt.days
```

One idea with convert `id` to index, but `max(level=0)` is only hidden `.groupby(level=0).max()`, so this should be trick solution (in my opinion)

```
max_diff_for_each_id = df.set_index('id').groupby("id")['date'].diff().max(level=0).dt.days
```

---

There is possible multiple `groupby` like:

```
max_diff_for_each_id = df.groupby("id")['date'].diff(1).groupby(df["id"]).max().dt.days
```

Or create custom functions like:

```
max_diff_for_each_id = df.groupby("id")['date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().max()).dt.days

max_diff_for_each_id = df.groupby("id")['date'].agg(lambda x: x.diff().max()).dt.days
```

---

```
print (max_diff_for_each_id)
id
1    5
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I would really like to avoid using `.apply` or `.agg` (edited the question)

Answer (score 1):

One way using `numpy.ptp`:

```
df.groupby("id").apply(np.ptp)
```

Output:

```
id
1   5 days
2   1 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Works fine with any number of values per each group

```
# print(df)
   id       date
0   1 2020-01-20
1   1 2020-01-25
2   1 2020-01-21
3   2 2020-02-03
4   2 2020-02-04
5   2 2020-02-06
6   2 2020-02-10

df.groupby("id").apply(np.ptp)
```

Output:

```
id
1   5 days
2   7 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: because in sample need `id
1   5 days
2   4 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]`

Comment: @jezrael You are right. max of diff is not same as ptp and i'm no longer sure if ptp is right approach. Let's wait for OP to comeback ;)

Comment: Yop, this solution sa same like @Dani Mesejo answer, only simplier.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could do:

```
groups = df.groupby('id')
result = groups['date'].max() - groups['date'].min()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
id
1   5 days
2   1 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

An alternative version:

```
frame = df.groupby('id').agg({'date': ['max', 'min']})
result = frame[('date', 'max')] - frame[('date', 'min')]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
id
1   5 days
2   1 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: sure, yop. Super.

Comment: My bad with the example (my `date` ranges from 1 date to around 100 dates, depending on the group) - it was just to illustrate